# Count the number of details in master-detail relationship

Tags: apex, soql, master-detail, aggregate, count

How can I count the number of details in master-detail relationship?

Let us suppose I have
**Detail_Type__c** and **Master_Type__c**.

Now if I have and `Id` of a **Master_Type__c** record I can do the following query:

```
List<Detail_Type__c> allDetails = [
 SELECT Id
 FROM Detail_Type__c
 WHERE Master_Type__c = :Id
];
Integer res = allDetails.size();
```

But I would like to be able to somehow do the query of the following form:

```
List<Master_Type__c> allDetails = [
 SELECT Master_Type_Field1__c, Master_Type_Field2__c, (SELECT NumberOf Detail_Type__r)
 FROM Detail_Type__c
 WHERE Master_Type_FieldDoesNotMatter_c = :something
];
```

In other words I would like to use something like an aggregate function to count the number of details in master-detail relationship for each detail in a list of details.

How can I do it?

Comment: I didn't understand, why standard roll-up summary field is not applicable here ?

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskiy, thank you for the idea about roll-up summary field. It would definitely solve the issue, but in a team I can not change data model, I can only use it.

Comment: Adding a new field won't be count as modding the data model. The roll-up summary will be more effective than querry plus the querry can timeout but the rollup field will not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `count` [aggregate function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm?search_text=aggre). You can have `Set<Id> masterIds = ...` in this case you can use `in` SOQL operator.

```
List<AggregateResult> result = [
    select count(Id)cnt, Master_Type__c
    from Detail_Type__c
    where Master_Type__c in :masterIds
    group by Master_Type__c
    ];

for (AggregateResult ar : result)  {
    System.debug('Master_Type__c' + ar.get('Master_Type__c'));
    System.debug('Count' + ar.get('cnt'));
}
```

Comment: Using `cnt` isn't the best abbreviation out there. I might recommend `records` or `childCount` or some such.